# Displaying dates using momentjs and getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript, html, momentjs

I'm trying to display an inputDate beautifully using momentJS in an outputDate class but I miss something to make it works probably in the script itself.

To uderstand the code, the idea is to nicely display, for each "article", the date in the output DIV which is taken from the input DIV aside. There is the same number of inputDate as outputDate.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<script src="moment-with-locales.js"></script>
<style>
.inputDate {diplay: none;}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<article>
<header>
    <p class="inputDate">2018-06-15 11:27:30</p>
    <p class="outputDate"></p>
</header>
<div id="question"><p>1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ?</p></div>
<div id="answer"><p>1.Amet sit dolor ipsum lorem.</p></div>
</article>

<article>
<header>
    <p class="inputDate">2019-07-18 15:15:45</p>
    <p class="outputDate"></p>
</header>
<div id="question"><p>2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ?</p></div>
<div id="answer"><p>2.Amet sit dolor ipsum lorem.</p></div>
</article>

<article>
<header>
    <p class="inputDate">2019-08-14 10:23:00</p>
    <p class="outputDate"></p>
</header>
<div id="question"><p>3.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ?</p></div>
<div id="answer"><p>3.Amet sit dolor ipsum lorem.</p></div>
</article>

<script type="text/javascript">
    (function()
    {
        // get the input date from inputDate class element
        var inputDates = document.getElementsByClassName("inputDate").innerHTML;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputDates.length; i++) {
            // use moment() with input value and a string format pattern as arguments
            var moDate[i] = moment(inputDates[i], "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
            // display the parsed date in a outputDate class element
            var outputDates = document.getElementsByClassName("outputDate");
            for (var j = 0; j < inputDates.length; j++) {
                // use moment() with input value and a string format pattern as arguments
                outputDates[j].innerHTML = moDate[i].locale("fr").format("LLL");
                }
        }
    }

    )();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For one, your id's aren't unique

Comment: Hello Bengo!  Could you add a link or text to the exact error(s) you are having? In addition, please read our [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: Yes: In my original code, nothing appears to be parsed by Javascript so it let the inputDate displayed as is (so displayed using it's ISO-8601 extended date during tests without display:none).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need one `for..loop` to do the work, note that I've used [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling) to get the next `p.outputDate` of each `p.inputDate` in the `inputDates` array:

```js
(function() {
    // get the input date from inputDate class element
    const inputDates = document.getElementsByClassName("inputDate");

    for (let i = 0; i < inputDates.length; i++) {
      // use moment() with input value and a string format pattern as arguments
      const moDate = moment(inputDates[i].innerHTML, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");

      // display the parsed date in a outputDate class element
      // use moment() with input value and a string format pattern as arguments
      const outputDate = inputDates[i].nextElementSibling;
      outputDate.innerHTML = moDate.locale("fr").format("LLL");
    }
  }

)();
```

```css
.inputDate {
  diplay: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <header>
    <p class="inputDate">2018-06-15 11:27:30</p>
    <p class="outputDate"></p>
  </header>
  <div id="question1">
    <p>1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="answer1">
    <p>1.Amet sit dolor ipsum lorem.</p>
  </div>
</article>

<article>
  <header>
    <p class="inputDate">2019-07-18 15:15:45</p>
    <p class="outputDate"></p>
  </header>
  <div id="question2">
    <p>2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="answer2">
    <p>2.Amet sit dolor ipsum lorem.</p>
  </div>
</article>

<article>
  <header>
    <p class="inputDate">2019-08-14 10:23:00</p>
    <p class="outputDate"></p>
  </header>
  <div id="question3">
    <p>3.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ?</p>
  </div>
  <div id="answer3">
    <p>3.Amet sit dolor ipsum lorem.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: Both of your responses are perfect and simple, I like your explainations and I overdoing the thing ! I like the the "nextElementSibling" so I will keep that. Thank you both again.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed your issue. Check the full working [codepen example here](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/57381cb909763d1bb7d1eb0849749cdb).

Your issues are here:

1) `var inputDates = document.getElementsByClassName("inputDate").innerHTML;`

here you don't grab an array of items as you planned, the result of this code line is undefined, cause of 'innerHTML'. You need to grab innerHTML of every single item in your loop, like that:

```
var moDate = moment(inputDates[i].innerHTML, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
```

2) `var moDate[i] = moment(inputDates[i], "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");`

you don't need the `[i]` part in `the moDate[i]`, cause you are looping an array and create unique moDate for each array item separately.

Also I've removed the inner loop, it's just redundant.

**Live demo:**

```js
(function() {
    // get the input date from inputDate class element
    var inputDates = document.getElementsByClassName("inputDate");
    var outputDates = document.getElementsByClassName("outputDate");

    for (var i = 0; i < inputDates.length; i++) {
      // use moment() with input value and a string format pattern as arguments
      var moDate = moment(inputDates[i].innerHTML, "YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss");
      // display the parsed date in a outputDate class element

      outputDates[i].innerHTML = moDate.locale("fr").format("LLL");
    }
  }

)();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.min.js"></script>
<article>
  <header>
    <p class="inputDate">2018-06-15 11:27:30</p>
    <p class="outputDate"></p>
  </header>
  <div class="question">
    <p>1.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>1.Amet sit dolor ipsum lorem.</p>
  </div>
</article>

<article>
  <header>
    <p class="inputDate">2019-07-18 15:15:45</p>
    <p class="outputDate"></p>
  </header>
  <div class="question">
    <p>2.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>2.Amet sit dolor ipsum lorem.</p>
  </div>
</article>

<article>
  <header>
    <p class="inputDate">2019-08-14 10:23:00</p>
    <p class="outputDate"></p>
  </header>
  <div class="question">
    <p>3.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet ?</p>
  </div>
  <div class="answer">
    <p>3.Amet sit dolor ipsum lorem.</p>
  </div>
</article>
```